# Node.js Express, receive application/octectstreams data

Tags: node.js, express

I need to build a http server able to receive raw data from a http client.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var data = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk){ data += chunk})
    req.on('end', function(){
       req.rawBody = data;
       next();
    })
 })


app.post('/api/v1/messages', async (clientReq, clientRes) => {

    const { path, headers, method, body, rawBody } = clientReq;

    console.log('contentLenght:', headers['content-length'])
    console.log('rawbody.length : ', rawBody.length);

}
```

I'm expecting the rawBody length to be the same of the content length but it is not.

```
Output:

contentLenght :  189
rawbody.length :>>  179
```

To debug the issue I've captured the traffic with wireshark. This is the client packet:

```
Frame 366: 343 bytes on wire (2744 bits), 343 bytes captured (2744 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 1
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 6, Src: ::1, Dst: ::1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54899, Dst Port: 3000, Seq: 129, Ack: 1149, Len: 279
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /api/v1/messages HTTP/1.1\r\n
    accept: */*\r\n
    host: localhost:3000\r\n
    content-length: 189\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/messages]
    [HTTP request 3/3]
    [Prev request in frame: 310]
    [Response in frame: 368]
    File Data: 189 bytes
    Data (189 bytes)
        Data: b77f44715e0b30140492dfc90e4fe7353f1f5a24943787d70919477518ee4e4243d176c7…
        [Length: 189]
```

The data size is equal of the content-length declared dimension.

The rawBody size is always smaller of 4 to 10 byte and the content is completely different form what I can see with wireshark.

Any idea on how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

i forgot to add the encoding in the middleware that decode the rawbody:

With the HEX encoding the rawbody size is correct.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    req.setEncoding('hex');
    var data = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk){ data += chunk})
    req.on('end', function(){
       req.rawBody = data;
       next();
    })
 })
```